# System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth Incorrect?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a web service (asp.net) that displays the height or width of the display that is attached to the server. However, when I invoke it via localhost I get the incorrect display, it says it is 1024x768 when really the display is set to 1280x1024.

Am I missing something here? The code is pretty simple:

```
[WebMethod]
public int GetHeight()
{
    return (int)System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
}

[WebMethod]
public int GetWidth()
{
    return (int) System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
}
```

I've also tried using:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
```

Perhaps there is a better way to do this? Maybe I should just store the values in a text file or perhaps there is a more reliable way? Perhaps querying the registry for the set resolution?

Comment: Is your web service running as a service that doesn't have access to the local desktop?

Comment: Are you sure they are running as the same user? Each user has their own display settings, so you'd need to login as the the same user as the web server.

Comment: @gabe: I believe so, is there a place I can check/configure this?

Comment: See http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3355/3291853278_280d0ba4cc_o.png

Comment: I'm using IIS and have checked that box for IIS Admin Service and restarted it but the web service is still reporting the incorrect display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up trying to get ASP.NET to work so I used WMI. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318836/detect-server-display-resolution) question that I asked and solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

It could have something to do with the data type seeing how the method returns a double. I would try using int.Parse() to cast to an integer.