# Detect Server Display Resolution

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

On windows server 2008 can I have a web service or something I can query from a C# application as to the display properties (resolution (height & width)). The C# application does not run on the server so I cannot just detect it from the application itself.

Addition to help explain why:

I will have a user named "display" and that will be logged on displaying a website (on the server) and I want to be able to check the display from the desktop application so the user knows what resolution to design a template for. The resolution will change from different displays so it can't be a set value.

Comment: Why would a client application not running on a server need to know display resolutions of a server (which might only have a command line interface, by the way)?

Comment: Are you asking for a client app to retrieve the display dimensions of the server screen?

Comment: do you mean the maximum resolution the graphic card on your server can support? Or the default resolution (`HLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\....\0000\DefaultSettings`)? Or the resolution set for a particular RDP user?

Comment: I will have a user named "display" and that will be logged on displaying a website (on the server) and I want to be able to check the display from the desktop application so the user knows what resolution to design a template for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend just querying the server using WMI. Check the third example here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, I finally got around to trying this and it worked well! I've accepted your answer as it was indeed the best answer and I've also added my code snippet to assist anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

**My Code**

This is the code that I used to solve the problem:

```
System.Management.ConnectionOptions oConnectionOptions = new System.Management.ConnectionOptions();
{
    oConnectionOptions.Username = ServerManagement.GetServerUser();
    oConnectionOptions.Password = ServerManagement.GetServerPassword();
}
ManagementPath oPath = new ManagementPath("\\\\" + ServerManagement.GetServerAddress() + "\\root\\cimv2");
ManagementScope oScope = new ManagementScope(oPath, oConnectionOptions);
try
{
    oScope.Connect();
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DesktopMonitor");
    ManagementObjectCollection obj = searcher.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject service in obj)
    {
        this.DisplayHeight = Convert.ToInt16(service["ScreenHeight"]);
        this.DisplayWidth = Convert.ToInt16(service["ScreenWidth"]);
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server, please try again later.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
}
```